# Understanding Profit and Loss chart with simple option strategy

Tags: india, put-options

I am using a platform called [Sensibull](https://web.sensibull.com/) and I am retail options trader in India, which follows European format of options.

I have shown below a profit and loss chart below
[image: screenshot]
[image]
The question that i have is according to the option bought it shows a green area i.e profit right until 18700pts but when i move my cursor(Nifty Target) to it, it shows loss can anyone explain me why this is so?
I think its cause of the blue line but not sure how that line is drawn?

Comment: It's just a standard option payoff plotted for various values of spot. You can see an example in the first [chart here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154996/109107/.) for a call. It looks like you sold a put option. Your projected profit is the money you receive from selling.